# ICollection<string> ValueComparer results in "Argument types do not match"

Tags: entity-framework

Following the [Collection of Primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#collections-of-primitives) sample code, I've made my own variation:

```cs
public class AttachmentTagsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Attachment>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Attachment> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.Tags).HasConversion(
            v => string.Join( ' ', v.Select(x => x.ToLower()).Distinct() ),
            v => v.Split( ' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
                .Select( x => x.ToLower() )
                .Distinct()
                .ToList(),
            new ValueComparer<ICollection<string>>(
                (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
                c => c.ToList()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Tags have no spaces, so we just join them together in the database to create a single string. This is what the schema looks like:

```cs
public class Attachment
{
    ...

    public ICollection<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

If I leave the `ValueComparer` in there, I get the following error when loading a query that has an `Attachment`:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Argument types do not match'

However, if I remove the `ValueComparer` it works fine. But then I assume change tracking won't work correctly?

I'm not sure what part of the comparer code could lead to an incorrect argument type. None of the records in the database have a `NULL` value for `Tags`, so I don't see how there could be any `null` values.

`Attachments` is an ancestor class - we have `AssetAttachments`, `InspectionAttachments`, `UnitAttachments` and `DefectAttachments`. Does this have an impact on the `SequenceEqual` comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see! I removed the casts that were in the original code:

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Attachment> builder)
{
    builder.Property( e => e.Tags ).HasConversion(
        v => string.Join( ' ', v.Select( x => x.ToLower()).Distinct() ),
        v => (ICollection<string>)v.Split( ' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
            .Select( x => x.ToLower() )
            .Distinct()
            .ToList(),
        new ValueComparer<ICollection<string>>(
            (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
            c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
            c => (ICollection<string>)c.ToList()
        )
    );
}
```

Visual Studio was showing me this:

[image: Visual Studio]

The cast is dimmed on the line highlighted! So I removed it when I shouldn't have!